# How to create useFetch wrapper on Nuxtjs3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I need to create a wrapper over useFetch so that if an error occurs, specifically 401, to perform user logout actions.

In logout I use the standard nuxt methods: `useLogout()`

```
export default async function() {
  const data = await useRequest('/api/auth/logout', { method: 'fetch'} )
  const user = useState('user', () => false);
  navigateTo('/auth');

  return {
    error: 401,
    success: false
  }
}
```

How i using request:

```
const { data, pending, error, execute }  = useReq('/api/test')
const tf = ref(false)

const sr = async () => {
  tf.value = true
  await execute();
  tf.value = false
}
```

```
export default function (link, body) {

  const params = {
    method: body ? 'POST' : 'GET',
    dedupe: 'defer',
    body
  }

  const errorValidator = async (data) => {
    if(data === 401 || data.data?.value?.error === 401) {
      useLogout()
    }
  }


  const data = useFetch(link, {
    ...params,
    onResponse: ({ request, response, options }) => {
     errorValidator(response)
    },
    onResponseError: ({response}) => {
      errorValidator(response._data.statusCode)
    }
  })

  return data
}
```

But I was very surprised that when the request is loaded on the first site load (SSR), no composables functions work inside the callback useFetch()

given an error:
`[nitro] [unhandledRejection] Error: [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug.`

And now I'm confused because I don't understand how to wrap useFetch to handle errors and do some action?

And im not using await, app rendering dynamically

Comment: dude can share a basic codesandbox or stackbliz file here. It will be much more easier for me to debug it.